# How to popup an image on press in react native

Tags: image, react-native, popup, react-native-lightbox

I want to magnify an image on press.

Here is my code

```
{
     this.state.data.file_name &&
     <Avatar
        xlarge
        source={{ uri: IMG_URL + this.state.data.file_name }}
        onPress={() => this.enlargeImage(IMG_URL + 
        this.state.data.file_name)}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        containerStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000', margin: 10 }}
     />
}

enlargeImage = (img) => {
return (
  <Lightbox underlayColor="white">
  <Image
    style={{flex: 1,height: 200}}
    resizeMode="contain"
    source={{ uri: img }}
  />
 </Lightbox>      
)
}
```

Now there is no response on image click. i'm using `react native lightbox`. Is there any alternative way to popup the image on touch?

Comment: are you looking for image viewer?

Comment: i just want to enlarge the image on click to show the full image to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the lightbox to the main avatar image

example:-

```js
{this.state.data.file_name &&
          <Lightbox style = {{flex: 1}}>
            <Avatar
        xlarge
        source={{ uri: IMG_URL + this.state.data.file_name }}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        containerStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000', margin: 10 }}
     />
          </Lightbox>
        }
```

You don't need to add the press event on the avatar
lightbox will automatically take the event.

Additional styling, you can use the properties of the lightbox.

[image: Here are the properties of the lightbox and the marked properties adds the custom styles and codes.]

Comment: how to style the enlarged image? now the image displays  with same size as in before.

Comment: please recheck my answer as i have updated the answer